# How do I avoid overwriting row values in Excel when writing value to excel file c# Selenium Automation

Tags: c#, excel

I am having trouble with this. I am running this selenium test and updating values that are in a spreadsheet. I am running these tests pararalley. Beacuse of that my method try to update the values in the same row. How do I change this to wait if excel file is used?

```
Reporting.Report(folder_Report, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), startTime, "Fail", error, lastScreenshot, GlobalVariables.orderNo, GlobalVariables.orderAmount, GlobalVariables.warnings);
            throw;'


public static void Report(string folder, string reportName,DateTime startTime, string statues, string error, string screenshot, string orderNo, string orderAmount, string warnings)
    {

        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan duration = endTime-startTime;

        string startTime_string = startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-d--HH-mm-ss");
        string endTime_string = endTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-d--HH-mm-ss");
        string duration_string = duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");


        string testCaseName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
        string testCaseDescription = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName;
        string xlfile = folder + "\\" + reportName ;
        string sheetName = "Sheet1";
        //string orderNo = GlobalVariables.orderNo;
        if (orderNo == "") orderNo = "NC";
        if (orderAmount == "") orderAmount = "n/a";

        string[] xlReport = new string[] { testCaseName, statues, orderNo, orderAmount, startTime_string, endTime_string, duration_string,  screenshot, warnings, error };
        ExcelEdit.UpdateXlWorkBook_nextRow(xlReport, folder, reportName, sheetName);

    }

 public static void UpdateXlWorkBook_nextRow(string[] MyInfo, string xlFolderPath, string xlWorkbookName, string sheetName)
    {
        var xlfile = xlFolderPath + "\\" + xlWorkbookName;
        if (xlWorkbookName == "") xlfile = xlFolderPath;

        ExcelWorkBook.Application xlApp = new ExcelWorkBook.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        ExcelWorkBook.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlfile, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, ExcelWorkBook.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        ExcelWorkBook.Sheets xlSheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
        ExcelWorkBook.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (ExcelWorkBook.Worksheet)xlSheets.get_Item(sheetName);

        //int col = xlWorkSheet.Columns.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.Count;
        int row = xlWorkSheet.Rows.CurrentRegion.EntireRow.Count;

        try
        {
            System.String Search1 = ((ExcelWorkBook.Range)xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E2", Type.Missing)).Value2 as string;
            int r = row+1; 
            int c = 1;                

            for (int counter = 0; counter < MyInfo.Length; counter++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[r, c] = MyInfo[counter];
                c++;
            }
            //Save As
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(xlfile);
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = ex;
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(xlfile);
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
    }
```